# How to create a showModalBottomSheet in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a modal bottom sheet like in image. Actually I know how to show and hide bottom sheet. But I have no idea how to achieve the show and hide button like image. May I know how to put the close and show button. Here is my current achievement.

```
class _FABState extends State<FAB> {
   bool isOpen = false;

   var bottomSheetController;

   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState(() {
      isOpen = !isOpen;
    });
    print('tapped on the bottom sheet');
    if(isOpen) {
      bottomSheetController = showBottomSheet(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          context: context,
          builder: (ctx) {
            return ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Container(
                height: 150,
                color: Colors.black,
                child: TextField()
              ),
            );
          });
      bottomSheetController.closed.then((value) {
        setState(() {
          isOpen = !isOpen;
        });
      });
    } else {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      setState(() {
        isOpen = !isOpen;
      });
    }
  },
  child: isOpen?Icon(Icons.arrow_downward):Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
);
 }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include your snippet for open/closing functionality?

Comment: I have edited in my question.